# How do I solve the following recursion $g(n) =\sqrt n\cdot g(\sqrt n) +2n + \frac{n-\sqrt n}2$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation :

> $$g(n) =\sqrt n\cdot g(\sqrt n) +2n + \frac{n-\sqrt n}2$$

The Master theorem does not fulfill because of $\sqrt n$, so I tried to change the variables $m=\log(n)$ and then got stuck when I placed: $S(m):=g(2^m)$

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: divide by $n\,$, then $\,
\frac{g(n)}{n}=\frac{g(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}
\,$.

Comment: Consider $$f(k)=2^{-2^k}g(2^{2^k})$$ and show that $$f(k)=f(k-1)+\frac52-\frac1{2^{1+2^{k-1}}}$$ hence $$f(k)=f(0)+\frac52k-\ldots=\Theta(\ldots)$$ which indicates that $$g(n)=\Theta(\ldots)$$

Comment: @Did and divx thank you both for answering ,I tried to merge your suggestions and I got                                                                                     2.5*log(log(n)) -0.5*( sqrt(n)^0.5 + sqrt(n)^0.25 + sqrt(n)^0.125 + ..+0.25             can you help me solve this ? I searched about sum of power series but I still do not know how to solve this.

Comment: @Did thank you I solved it : O(nloglogn)